# Sum of Determinants of two Orthogonal Matrices

Tags: matrices

If $A$ and $B$ are two orthogonal matrices of rank $n$ and $Det(A)+Det(B)=0$,then prove or disprove that $Det(A+B)=0$.

My attempt: Since the two matrices are orthogonal the value of their determinants will either be $1$ or $-1$. But how to prove that $Det(A+B)=Det(A)+Det(B)$

Comment: Thanks a lot @LeGrandDODOM

Answer (score 2):

For two orthogonal matrices $A, \ B$, $Det(A+B)\neq Det(A)+Det(B)$. This is a counterexample: 
\begin{align*}
&A=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}, \
&B=\begin{bmatrix}
-1 & 0 \\
0 & -1
\end{bmatrix}. \\
\end{align*}

Comment: Note that $\det(A)+\det(B)=2\ne 0.$